# Nifi Routing for Kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, routes, apache-nifi

I am trying to write a simple workflow where I read a csv file, convert it to JSON and based on the existence of an element in JSON route that specific JSON object to a Kafka topic. For example, I have 2 JSON records that have "env":"prod" in one and "env":"dev" in another. Based on the env I want that particular JSON record to go to a specific Kafka topic.

I am able to convert the CSV to JSON. However, I am unsure of how to read a specific element from the JSON record and then route. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Please elaborate concisely if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use two Processors [EvaluateJSONPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) and [RouteOnAttriute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnAttribute/) to achieve this.

The links have elaborate documentation bout the usage. Hope it will helpful. I have used the same in one my similar use case.